# how to get a list of "scores" for each type from a sql query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a table returned with "weighted score" with a formula that i designed for each type for the following schema:

favorite: userID, drinkName

history: userID, drinkName

drink: name, directions, type

drinker: idNum, userID, password

Let each drink in history be worth 0.666 points and each drink in favorite worth 1 point.

so each time lets say a drink with type vodka shows up in history 0.666 should be added to the numerator for a specific userID. And 1 point for favorites for the vodka total. 
Then it should be divided by the total number of drinks the userID has in both favorites and history.

So for example, I have 3 vodkas in history and 2 in favorites, it should be: 
(3(0.666)+2)/5

And the query should return this for all "types" of drinks I have available with the greatest at top.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT (
( SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   Drink D JOIN History  H ON H.drinkName = D.name
    WHERE  type = 'vodka' AND userID = 'sai') 
+ 
(((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   Drink D JOIN Favorite F ON F.drinkName = D.name
    WHERE  type = 'vodka' AND userID = 'sai'))*0.666))
 /  
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM History  WHERE userID = 'sai') 
+ 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Favorite WHERE userID = 'sai'))
```

However this only returns for a specific type of drink but not table of every type of drink.

Comment: You tagged both mysql and sql-server... which one is it?

Comment: sorry that was by accident, its only mysql

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` along with aggregation functions to get per-type totals.

```
SELECT type, SUM(numerator)/SUM(denominator) score
FROM (
    SELECT type, COUNT(*) numerator, COUNT(*) denominator
    FROM History
    WHERE userID = "sai"
    GROUP BY type
    UNION ALL
    SELECT type, (COUNT(*) * 0.666) numerator, COUNT(*) denominator
    FROM Favorites
    WHERE userID = "sai"
    GROUP BY type
) u
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bit of a schema problem. There doesn't seem to be a need to track drink history in two different tables based on whether the user has it marked as favorite or not.  I would think a drink history should track all drink regardless of whether they are favorites or not while favorites should indicate only what the drinks are that the person currently has tagged as favorite.

So taking your 5 drink example earlier, I would say your tables might look like:

history

```
userId drinkName someTimeField
sai    vodka     2013-12-09 12:30:53
sai    tequila   2013-12-09 12:31:23
sai    rum       2013-12-09 12:31:53
sai    vodka     2013-12-09 12:32:23
sai    beer      2013-12-09 12:32:53
```

So beside knowing that Sai might have a drinking problem (because you know when he had his drinks) you have a full histroy of what he dranks regardless as to whether the drinks were "favorites"

favorite

```
userId  drinkNane
sai     vodka
sai     everclear
```

Now you simply do a single easy join to get your calculation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.drinkName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0.66 END CASE)
    /SUM(1) AS `value`
FROM drinker AS d
LEFT JOIN history AS h
  ON d.userId = h.userId
LEFT JOIN favorite AS f
  ON h.userId = f.userId AND h.drinkName = f.drinkName
WHERE d.drinker = ?
GROUP BY d.drinker
```